# Mongoose query array of Refrences

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

Im trying to query an employeer where it has services with mongoose, and it returns an empty array, and i cant figure out why it happends, cause when i do the same in mongolab it returns it fine.

on my Employeer model i got

```
services:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Service'
}]
```

The Query im trying to execute in mongolab that works

```
{
"services": {
    "$in": [
        "5c3cd01e9eed727bd4584753"
    ]
}}
```

the query i execute in mongoose and not work

```
await Employeer.find({
            "services": {
                "$in": [
                    "5c3cd01e9eed727bd4584753"
                ]
            }
        }).exec();
```

It should return the same as in mongolab query but it return null instead.I tried to cast it to ObjectId aswell but nothing works

Comment: can you show the whats the output of `await Employeer.find({"services":"5c3cd01e9eed727bd4584753"}).exec();`

Comment: [] empty array is the output

Comment: so , i guess there is no docs, correspnding to search

Comment: Like i wrote in the article IT Works directly on the database on mlab. But when its done in mongoose with the same database and query No data so yes Therese is a document

Comment: there there must be some problem, may be the collection name its pointiong to is different. please check that too.